# How to say it right: "none" or "noone"

Tags: word-usage, pronunciation

Let's assume the following dialog:

- Any questions?
- None [nAn] from me.

But I heard something like *noone* from a native speaker. Is it possible to say so or it was just an accent/dialect?

Answer (score 1):

For the proper pronunciation of "none", go to this page, http://www.thefreedictionary.com/none, and click on the speaker icon. It's a short "u' sound, like "nun".

If someone said "Noon from me", it's probably just an accent or perhaps he's altering the vowel for emphasis or comic effect.